# Backbone doesn't pass AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, backbone.js

I have a Laravel app which is forwarding an URL to the Backbone:

```
urlContainer['userAjax'] = "{!! RoutingService::actionAjax('AccountController@getUserAjax') !!}";
```

And backbone gets it:

```
App.Models.User = bb.Model.extend({
    url: urlContainer.userAjax,
});
```

Later on I call it like this:

```
var userLogged = new App.Models.User();
userLogged.fetch();
```

The problem I'm having is that the middleware I made in Laravel doesn't register it as AJAX call:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($request->url());

    if (key_exists('path', $parsedUrl) && strpos($parsedUrl['path'], '-ajax') !== false && !$request->ajax()) {
        return response('Bad request', 400);
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

First two conditions are true, but the last one is not. It is behaving like it is not an AJAX request?

Comment: Can you see your request in Network tab (Chrome Dev Toolbar)? If so could you please dump it here?

Comment: What part of it? It is calling the right route and method. When I comment out the middleware it works fine

Comment: Although, it is working on main domain, but giving error on subdomain.

Comment: So you said that your request is not acting like an xhr request. can you show those headers of that request? In Chrome Developer Tools you can navigate to Network tab and do right-click on your request and click Copy->Copy Request Headers. Because I have no idea what's going on there in your app